# Is Ireland setting itself up for a debt crisis?

Tags: macroeconomics, banking

I'm just curious about some things I read in a banking report. It says more than 20% total bank loans in Ireland are Non-performing loans which are likely to default.

> "With the NPL ratio for households at 26% for non-financial
>    corporations - 44% for SMEs - and 44% for commercial real estate."

Then it goes on to say that Credit to non-financial corporations in 2015, was 267% of GDP. The current value of the bad loans is around $50 billion.

Is this a bad situation, or do the numbers make it look worse than it actually is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your figures seem to come from a European Central Bank analysis published in September 2016 for the position at the end of 2015

Different people get different numbers, but the order of magnitude is probably credible

But this sort of number has been coming down compared with previous years.  For example [IMF publishes the following graph](http://data.worldbank.org/indicator/FB.AST.NPER.ZS?locations=IE)

[image]